# Download file from website on Android's Chrome- Java

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, http, servlets

I'm trying to download an.APK on Android's Chrome from my Glassfish server, but all I got is a "**zero** kb" file.

On Windows(PC)'s Chrome and on Android's Firefox it works correctly.

I'm using the following code:

```
    private void downloadAPK(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, PrintWriter out){

            String file = "/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/foo/foo.apk";

            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            try{
                    File downloadFile = new File(file);
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+file.getName());
                    int c = 0;

                    while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1)
                            out.write(c);
            } catch (Exception e) {
             // code
            }
            // closing code
    }
```

There is something that I'm missing to make it work on Android's Chrome?